# is it possible to store several values in a structure?

Tags: c, structure

I am new at c , and I was wondering if it's possible to store  many values in a structure ? . I wanted to store more than 1 value of x1,y1,x2,y2. And after that I want a random value x1,y1,x2,y2. Is that possible with a struct or I need to use an other tool ?

```
struct test
{
    int x1;
    int y1;
    int x2;
    int y2;
};
```

Comment: What do you mean???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need an array.

```
#include <time.h> //you need this to use time(NULL)
#include <stdlib.h> //you need this for random numbers functions
#include <stdio.h> //you need this for printf

//this is called a macro, it will get replaced by value 10 everywhere in the following code
#define NUM_OF_VALUES 10

struct test
{
    int x1[NUM_OF_VALUES];
    int y1[NUM_OF_VALUES];
    int x2[NUM_OF_VALUES];
    int y2[NUM_OF_VALUES];
}

int main() {

    struct test my_test = { /* learn about initializes */ };

    srand(time(NULL)); //this is how you initialize random number generator to be different every time you run your code

    printf("Random value from x1 %d\n", my_test.x1[rand() % NUM_OF_VALUES]);
    printf("Random value from y1 %d\n", my_test.y1[rand() % NUM_OF_VALUES]);

    return 0;
}
```

Read here about how you can manually put some values in this `struct` for testing: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization

Comment: I'm not sure *what* the heck the OP wants.  But yes: using arrays for the struct's members is a good guess - and a good solution.  Or perhaps the OP is looking for an array of structs (an alternate theory).  Who knows - maybe he wants x1, y1, x2 and y2 to contain quantum values, that aren't determined until Schroedinger's cat looks at them :(

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili good point, I amended the code and added the includes too